# Unable to remove all UITableView cells with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can's seem to be able to remove all table rows. What seems to happen is that only the cells that are in view are removed and then the ones that were out of view move up. Also checked and my data source contains only the cels that are in view at the time of deletion. Heres the code

```
NSMutableArray *left = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *right = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<dataSource.count;i++){
    [dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    if(i%2==0)
        [left addObject:ip];
    else
        [right addObject:ip];
}
[_view.tableView beginUpdates];
[_view.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:left]
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[_view.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithArray:right]
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[_view.tableView endUpdates];
```

What happens now is that only the cells in view are removed and the rest pop in after the removal (also the issue seems to pop up since the dataSource only contains the rows that are in view for some reason). What i want is to remove all the rows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `for` loop condition. The `dataSource.count` gets smaller each iteration. Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<dataSource.count;i++){
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    if(i%2==0)
        [left addObject:ip];
    else
        [right addObject:ip];
}
[dataSource removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
[_view.tableView beginUpdates];
UITableViewRowAnimation animation;
for(int i = dataSource.count - 1; i>= 0; i--)
{
    [dataSource removeObjectAtIndex: i];

    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i
                                         inSection: 0];
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        animation = UITableViewRowAnimationLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        animation = UITableViewRowAnimationRight;
    }

    [_view.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ip]]
                           withRowAnimation: animation];
}
[_view.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in easy way...

```
[dataSource removeAllObjects];
[_view.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score -1):

i think that you can put your `dataSource = @[];` and `[self.tableview reloadData];` and  remove all cell in your tableview

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: dataSource = @[];
[self.tableview reloadData];